# Por que me da este error? Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ' '

Tags: php

Tengo mi clase php:

```
    <?php
    class Service {    
    private $servicio;
    private $db;
    private $procesos;

    public function __construct() {
        //$this->servicio = array();
        $this->procesos = array();
        $this->$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "prospera");
    }


    private function setNames() {
        return $this->db->query("SET nombre 'utf8'");
    }

    public function getServicios() {

        self::setNames();
        $sql = "SELECT id, nombre, precio FROM tbproducto";
        foreach ($this->db->query($sql) as $res) {
            $this->servicio[] = $res;
        }
        return $this->servicio;
        $this->db = null;
    }

    public function setServicio($nombre, $precio) {

        self::setNames();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbproducto(nombre, precio) VALUES ('" . $nombre . "', '" . $precio . "')";
        $result = $this->db->query($sql);

        if ($result) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function getListaProcesos(){
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT proceso2 FROM tbuniverso WHERE proceso2 LIKE '%B2_18'";
        foreach ($this->db->query($sql) as $res ) {
            $this->procesos[] = $res;

        }
        return $this->procesos;
        $this->db = null;
    }

}
?>
```

esta clase es de donde obtengo los datos de la DB, para llenar una lista desplegable, esta clase se comunica con otra clase que utilizo como controlador:

```
    <?php   
    require ("modelo.php");
    require_once ("../index.php");
    $services = new Service();
    $datos = $services->getListaProcesos();
    ?>
```

El problema es que cuando ejecuto la pagina donde esta mi formulario me manda este error php: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '  ' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in C:\wamp64\www\webprueba\php\modelo.php on line 2
Lo que entiendo es que espera un parametro pero no estoy seguro, si  me podrian orientar en este asunto, gracias.

Comment: No se que contiene `modelo.php`, pero el error es de sintaxis, esta esperando una función o constante y le diste un string.

Comment: hola, el archivo modelo.php es la clase que pegue primero donde me comunico con la BD, se me paso decirlo.

Comment: Me parece que se te fue un $ de mas en esta linea. `$this->$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "prospera");` Compara a como haces las demas llamadas a db.

Comment: Puedes añadir la linea donde te marca ese error?

Comment: si, parece que si se me fue pero me sigue enviando el mismo error.

Comment: Te faltara tal vez el require_once en require ("modelo.php"); ?

Comment: es esta linea: class Service {  , donde inicia mi clase.

Comment: Copie tu código e hice la prueba de inclusión de archivos pero no da el error que indicas, yo probaría primero a reiniciar el servicio apache y si no funciona comenzaría a aislar el error comentando el código del archivo modelo.php intentando acotar el problema, además del error cuando asignas la propiedad db no veo nada extraño y menos algo que genere el error que dices tener. Corregir `$this->$db = new mysqli` quitando el símbolo `$` de `->$db`

Answer (score -2):

Ya pude resolverlo, gracias gente. Bueno mi solución fue que el compilador detectaba espacios en blanco después de cada linea de código, no se por que pero fui linea por linea eliminando todo espacio en blanco y así se fue corrigiendo, como me comentaron aquí no había mayor error "visible" en el código pero me queda la duda de por que me detectaba como error los espacios entre lineas, saben ustedes por que?.

Comment: en que partes eliminaste dichos espacios en blanco?

Comment: bueno mas especifico, ejemplo: en la linea que me enviaba error, class Service {, lo que hacia era posicionar el cursor después de la llave de cierre y con suprimir eliminaba los espacios hasta que la siguiente linea se juntaba, no se si me explico...